# Как настроить "кухню" gulp+livereload+php+sass?

Tags: gulp

Вся соль в livereload и php , хотелось бы использовать сервер из gulp или openserver , только как настроить? Может у кого есть готовое решение?

Comment: Речь идет об обычном PHP приложении? Или о чем-то на базе React.php (или схожем решении)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

У меня php висит на vagrant, на локальном домене. Не забудьте пробросить порт для vagrant. Gulp запускаю на хост машине под виндой. В результате что то типа того:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "mysite.local",
        port: '8008',
        open: false
    });
});
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src([path.src.js + '/**/*.js'])
        ...
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'scripts', 'styles', 'copy-fonts'], function () {
    gulp.watch(path.src.styles + '/**/*.scss', ['styles', browserSync.reload]);
});
```